# Reading XML within XML using Java

Tags: java, xml

How to read From XML <returnMsg>Successful</returnMsg> value of this tag in java?
How to read the data of the tags in this example.
I am getting The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Exception is getting

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <doServiceResponse xmlns="http://ocs.ztesoft.com">
                        <doServiceReturn>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;

&lt;zsmart&gt;

  &lt;Data&gt;
    &lt;header&gt;
      &lt;returnMsg&gt;Successful&lt;/returnMsg&gt;
      &lt;ACTION_ID&gt;ModifyBalReturnAllBal&lt;/ACTION_ID&gt;
      &lt;REQUEST_ID&gt;0032013070900000503&lt;/REQUEST_ID&gt;
      &lt;returnCode&gt;0&lt;/returnCode&gt;
    &lt;/header&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;


      &lt;TransactionSN&gt;503&lt;/TransactionSN&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
  &lt;/Data&gt;
&lt;/zsmart&gt;
            </doServiceReturn></doServiceResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

JAVA CODE

```
dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(respString));
            doc = db.parse(is);
            nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Envelope");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);



                NodeList txnStatus = element.getElementsByTagName("returnCode");
                Element line = (Element) txnStatus.item(0);
                bean.setTxnStatus(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));



                NodeList message = element.getElementsByTagName("returnMsg");
                line = (Element) message.item(0);
                bean.setMessage(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
            }
```

Exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

Comment: add your code and error

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to convert `XML` file to `JAVA OBJECT`.
`SAX` and `JAXB` algorithms are two of them.
`JAXB` algorithm is more easily to use. i prefer to use `JAXB`.
HERE is the link that helps you to create Object from `XML` file.
enjoy it...

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/